# UIWebView embedded video incorrectly rotated in fullscreen

Tags: ios, ipad, video, uiwebview, fullscreen

Note: My application builds on iOS 5.1 and the .plist files are set to only support Landscape orientation.

I have a `UIWebView` that has an embedded video in it. When I tap the video's fullscreen button, the fullscreen video is rotated to be in portrait orientation, regardless of any lock on the iPad's orientation. This only appears to happen with iPads running iOS 7 (and the iPad 7.0 Simulator). The `UIViewController` for the `UIWebView` has a `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method implemented, but it does not get called.

Is there any way I can figure out where this fullscreen view is being created and controlled by? If I can find this (possibly modal?) view of the iOS native video player, or its controller, I can place the `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method in that controller class or just transform the view to ensure it rotates properly. That said, I don't know what the view is a subview of, or how to access it.

I should also note that through much searching I found the `UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification` notification, which is useful but I do not believe it gives me access to the view for the video.

Any thoughts or insight would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hey @Charlie did you manage to make any progress on this? I have the exact same problem in iOS 7.

Comment: It seems like it was fixed on iOS 7.0.3, I am not sure what the changes were but it appears to have done something to fix it. I didn't change anything but it now works. I hope it is fixed on your end as well.